# Javascript - Backbone - Code throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, mustache

The code below is throwing an error - "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" in mustache.js at this section of code in it.- "

```
function quote(text) {
    var escaped = text.replace(jsCharsRe, function (c) {
      return "\\u" + ('0000' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
    });"
```

This is my code

```
<%@  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="VSBackboneDemo._Default" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>VS backbone demo</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://github.com/janl/mustache.js/raw/master/mustache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        EmployeeDataView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function () {

                this.render();
            },
            render: function () {

                var data = {
                    employees: [
                { firstName: "Mickey",
                    lastName: "Mouse",
                    employeeID: 10000,
                    jobTitle: "Software Developer"
                },
                { firstName: "Donald",
                    lastName: "Duck",
                    employeeID: 20000,
                    jobTitle: "Software Engineer"
                },
                { firstName: "Bugs",
                    lastName: "Bunny",
                    employeeID: 30000,
                    jobTitle: "UI tester"
                },
                ]
                };

                var tpl = "Employees:<ul>{{#employees}}<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}" +
                    "{{employeeID}}{{jobTitle}}</li>{{/employees}}</ul>";

                var html = Mustache.to_html(tpl, data);

                $('#EmployeeDataContainer').html(html);


            }

        });


        var EmployeeDataView = new EmployeeDataView({ el: $("#EmployeeDataContainer") });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="EmployeeDataContainer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have a stray trailing comma in `data.employees`:

```
var data = {
    employees: [
        // ...
        { firstName: "Bugs",
          lastName: "Bunny",
          employeeID: 30000,
          jobTitle: "UI tester"
        }, // <------------------------- Right here
    ]
};
```

All the other JavaScript parsers (incorrectly) ignore the trailing comma but IE (at least older ones) slip a `null` into your array so they see `data` as this:

```
var data = {
    employees: [
        // ...
        { firstName: "Bugs",
          lastName: "Bunny",
          employeeID: 30000,
          jobTitle: "UI tester"
        },
        null
    ]
};
```

Then the `{{#employees}}` in your Mustache template ends up trying to use a `null` and everything falls apart.

Remove that trailing comma and everything should work fine.

Comment: Yes this is a valid bug, I had noticed it and fixed it as well. But that wasn't all the bugs there was.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `type="text/javascript"` to this line

```
<script src="http://github.com/janl/mustache.js/raw/master/mustache.js"></script>
```

So change it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/janl/mustache.js/raw/master/mustache.js"></script>
```

What is happening here is that your browser interprets your mustache.js file as Microfosft JScript, which is not Javascript.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well I've fixed it, there were three problems with it.

1) the comma issue, the one where "mu is too short" is correctly
identified as well.

2) You gotta wrap the entire script around      `$(function() {
..........       });` else it won't display properly.

3) The latest version of mustache gave me the errors, when I used an
older one it worked fine.